# ¿Cómo insertar una variable de entorno desde un archivo .env en pwa react para manifest.webmanifest?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, pwa

Tengo una situación con un PWA de reacción en el que necesito que el manifiesto de la aplicación tome los valores del archivo de configuración .env. He intentado hacerlo de las siguientes maneras, pero no se muestra la propiedad de nombre del manifiesto:

```
"nombre": "REACT_APP_MANIFEST_NAME",
"nombre": "%REACT_APP_MANIFEST_NAME%",
"nombre": "$((REACT_APP_MANIFEST_NAME))",
"nombre": "((REACT_APP_MANIFEST_NAME))",
"nombre": REACT_APP_MANIFEST_NAME,
"nombre": %REACT_APP_MANIFEST_NAME%.
"nombre": $((REACT_APP_MANIFEST_NAME)),
"nombre": ((REACT_APP_MANIFEST_NAME)),
```

Esto es lo que me muestra cuando agrego el PWA a la pantalla de inicio:
[image: screenshot icono y name PWA]

Aclaro que los valores los estaría tomando, de igual manera llamo dinámicamente a los íconos a través de una variable de entorno que almacena los datos de la ruta del ícono. El problema ocurre en el nombre de descarga de la PWA. ¡Gracias de antemano por cualquier sugerencia! PD: Si considerando que la información que dejo está incompleta o que es incomprensible, acepto la sugerencia para la edición, estaba buscando mucha información sobre este tema y hay poco sobre los manifiestos dinámicos (sin ser con subdominios ) de la PWA con React.